# Javascript library for making chart

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, html, charts

I am looking for a JavaScript library for drawing HTML5 charts. It should:

- be open source
- support animations and transitions (changing content with sliding)
- be simple to use
- support mixed types, i.e. bar chart with line chart
- being themable is a must

Comment: Just charts, or a full report generation solution?

Comment: Just charts but I'm no more looking for one not

Comment: You might want to ask at the new Code Recommendations on Area51 - "Proposed Q&A site for programmers seeking the best library for specific tasks" area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations

Answer (score 2):

ZingChart meets your requirements, but it is not open source. However, we do offer a free, branded version if cost is the concern.

- Animations - There are [animation](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/animation/) options available for effect,
  delay, method, sequence, and speed.
- Simple to use- Setting up charts is similar to other charting
  libraries if you have that experience. ZingChart has a CSS-like
  syntax.
- Support mixed charts- Mixed is set up by assigning "type":"mixed" and
  then placing the other chart types within the "series" object. Here
  is an example from the [gallery](http://www.zingchart.com/gallery/?ID=27359)
- Themable - ZingChart offers many [pre-built themes](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/themes/), as well as the
  option to apply a custom theme.

*I'm on the ZingChart team, so if you have any questions about features or licensing feel free to reach out.*

Answer (score 2):

Just surprised that no one has so far mentioned what is probably the most popular and powerful option: http://d3js.org/

Take a look at the plethora of examples to see what it is capable of. Powerful and easy to learn & use.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Answer (score 0):

[LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/) meets these requirements, and it's free for personal use. It's not open-source though, but with WebGL GPU acceleration and extreme optimization, the performance is the best in the industry.